# Do you need energy to exert a force?

Tags: forces, energy

Is force dependent or independent of energy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To augment what [tpg2114 wrote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90449/22494), work is usually defined as: $$W = fd$$ Where $W$ is the total work done, $f$ is the force, and $d$ is the distance (actually it's the $\Delta d$ caused by the force).

As long as $d = 0$ no work is being done.

For example, if you're standing on the surface of the Earth, energy is not being consumed to keep you from falling through the ground, even though a force is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f = -\frac{dE}{dx}$ you don't need "energy" per se, you just need a gradient of energy between the two states.

On the other hand, force is independent of work because it's possible to have forces that do no work.

Comment: @BMS: $\mathbf{F}=\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}$, not $\frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dx}$. If we wanted to get technical, there should be a negative sign in front: $F_x=-\frac{dE}{dx}$.

Comment: Clearly I wrote it in a big hurry without thinking about what I was writing :) Feel free to fix any other technical inaccuracies you might see... I should think a bit more before posting.